# How can I improve my logging in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Can anyone help with advice or resources on useful logs in Rails.

At the moment, I have the following line in my Apache virtual host:

```
CustomLog <loglocation>
LogLevel warn
```

My main issue is dealing with support requests. Recently a customer stated that they couldn't create a user in the application. I could see a 500 error in the log and I have the following line in my Users controller create method:

```
Rails.logger.debug(@user.errors.inspect)
```

But nothing appears in the log.

I've now had another customer say that email notifications have not been received and I have nowhere to start looking for the problem.

Any thoughts/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Robin

Comment: try this `https://rubygems.org/gems/logger` developed by Hiroshi

Answer (score 0):

Install exception_notifier gem or use airbrake. There are wide variety of notification systems available to track these kind of errors https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/exception_notification